# PostgreSQL function parameters not being passed correctly

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function that takes in an argument which is meant to be passed to a **RETURN QUERY** and the data is fed in from an underlying view.
Now I get zero rows when I execute the function but when I run the select statement on it's own I get results. 
So part of me thinks that the 
function parameter is not being read at all. Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

```
create or replace function my_trans(IN inid character)
RETURNS TABLE(
  a_date timestamp without time zone, 
  pnt_sys character, 
  nval numeric, 
  pnt_type character, 
  gpid integer)  
as $$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 
             BORN_DATE,
             MY_SYSTEM,
             MY_VALUE,
             MY_TYPE,
             MY_PAY_ID
     FROM vw_psr where nid ~* '$1';
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: `(IN inid character varying)` or `(IN inid text)` , supposing you want a *string* argument.

Comment: Also, do not quote the placement of your parameter (`$1`) -- it will mean literally the string `'$1'` (you can use the identifier `inid` too because you named your parameter). Also note that in its current state a `LANGUAGE sql` function might be better suited for your needs.

Comment: @joop.. cheers.. tried that, no luck, although I think that's hardly the issue.

Comment: The wierd thing is if I re-crate the function without parameters and no filter on the where clause then the function essentially works but not what I want.

Comment: @pozs .. That's has worked for me .. Smashing stuff, thanks a bunch!!

Comment: `create or replace function my_trans(IN inid character)
RETURNS TABLE(
  a_date timestamp without time zone, 
  pnt_sys character, 
  nval numeric, 
  pnt_type character, 
  gpid integer)  
as $$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 
             BORN_DATE,
             MY_SYSTEM,
             MY_VALUE,
             MY_TYPE,
             MY_PAY_ID
     FROM vw_psr where nid ~*  $1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your function:

1. don't use `character` - use `text` or `varchar` instead
2. don't put parameter names in single quotes

Unrelated to your problem, but a simple "SELECT function" is better written as a plain SQL function:

```
create or replace function my_trans(p_inid text)
RETURNS TABLE(
  a_date timestamp without time zone, 
  pnt_sys character, 
  nval numeric, 
  pnt_type character, 
  gpid integer)  
as $$
    SELECT BORN_DATE,
           MY_SYSTEM,
           MY_VALUE,
           MY_TYPE,
           MY_PAY_ID
    FROM vw_psr 
    where nid ~* p_inid;
$$ language sql;
```

It's also a good coding convention to use some kind of prefix for parameters and local variables to avoid a name clash between them and column names.

Comment: spot on .. thanks for your suggestions. It's been very helpful indeed.